# Google Spell API and TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, google-api, google-search-api

I just successfully implemented the spell checking plugin for TinyMCE using the instructions [here](http://ondotnet.deap.nu/2009/01/implementing-tinymce-spellchecker-with.html).  I got a bit scared, though, by this ending paragraph.

> I've had some trouble finding good documentation of the Google Spell
>   Service and [it seems as if it is no longer updated but still
>   available to developers already using it](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/index.html) (which should include the
>   TinyMCE .Net package even though you haven't used it before). However,
>   use at your own risk should Google decide to delete it. This is the
>   only official documentation I can find and that isn't much...

Am I to understand this to mean that the spell checking service used by Moxiecode.TinyMCE.dll points to an unsupported, abandoned api from Google?

**EDIT**

It seems as though the spell checking is happening via a post to `https://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?...` as decribed [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2005/07/19/419838.aspx).

Is this service documented anywhere?

Comment: I am also using the service and now it's not working from last few days (almost from 11 July 2013). It's an urgent issue for me, how can we resolve this or is there any other replacement or solutions?