# transform short word to original word

Tags: java, text, text-to-speech, text-analysis, text-recognition

I used some word counting algorithm and by a closer look I was wondering because I got out less words than originally in the text because they count for example "it's" as one word. So I tried to find a solution but without any success, so I asked myself if their exist anything to transform a "short word" like "it's" to their "base words", say "it is".

Comment: where is your code ? What is the algorithm you used ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically you need to provide a data structure that maps abbreviated terms to their corresponding long versions. However, this will not be as simple as it sounds, for example you won't want to transform *"The client's car."* to *"The client is car."*

To manage these cases, you will probably need a heuristic that has a deeper understanding of the language you are processing and the grammar rules it incorporates.

Comment: The example you mentioned is the reason why I am asking myself if such a tool already exist ;)

Comment: Spell checking API may provide such features, but I suppose they will only use them internally. Did you check how open source tools such as OpenOffice implement word counting?

Comment: Thanks I will check the API

Comment: I tried the spell checker api's found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268998/google-spell-api-and-tinymce however they see it is and it's as correct as it is ;) So spell checkers can not be used for that purpose unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I just built this from scratch for the challenge. It seems to be working on my end. Let me know how it works for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "it's such a lovely day! it's really amazing!";

    System.out.println(convertText(s));
    //output: it is such a lovely day! it is really amazing!

}

public static String convertText(String text) {
    String noContraction = null;
    String replaced = null;
    String[] words = text.split(' ');

    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.contains("'s")) {
            String replaceAposterphe = word.replace("'", "$");
            String[] splitWord = replaceAposterphe.split('$');
            noContraction = splitWord[0] + " is";
            replaced = text.replace(word, noContraction);
        }
    }
    return replaced;
}
```

I did this in C# and tried to convert it into Java. If you see any syntax errors, please point them out.

Comment: Thanks but this algorithm has the same problem it is converting for example "The client is car." to "The client is car."

Comment: I think you meant to say "The client's car" to "The client is car." Something like that, as mentioned by user1438038, would need an algorithm that is built in such a way to know the difference between possessive's and plurals. I'm sure that can be done, but that would be one crazy algorithm.